# How to make IP address fields validation?

Tags: inno-setup

I've created a custom form with four seperate IP address fields for each node of the address. I don't know how to restrict the entry into these fields so it will only accept numeric values between 0 and 255.

How to make IP address fields validation ?

Comment: Restricting might be confusing. You should rather validate those fields on exit. Consider what you do if I type e.g. numbers 2, 5 and then 6. Would you let me write 2 and 5 and the last 6 not ? Could you elaborate how do you imagine such *"restriction"* ?

Comment: Also keep in mind what to do if the user will paste a value like `256` from clipboard into an edit box.

Comment: I view the restriction as either displaying an error message on the user trying to tab to the next value or defaulting to 255. So, using your example, when the user pastes '256' into the field and attempts to move to another field, the form would amend the value to 255.